# Failed to lookup view "index" in views using handlebars with nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have an index.handlebars file in my views folder but I still got this error message

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory
```

Below is my app.js file.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var exphbs = require('express3-handlebars')

app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
});

app.use('/public', express.static('public'));

var port = Number(process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.listen(port);
```

Any thought? I felt so strange, it seems everything were right to me.

Comment: Try to rename `index.handlebars` to `home.handlebars`. Perhaps `index` is a special name in `node.js`.

Comment: @TomaszJakubRup nope.

Comment: Can you recheck if the file you have is exactly `views/index.handlebars` in the *app.js* folder? I have copy-pasted your exact code and it works for me.

Comment: Of course You have `views/layout/main.handlebars` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked out your Github repo regarding this problem.

It seems that you have mistyped the name of the view. It's currently `index.handlerbars` while it should be `index.handlebars`.

Comment: damn what a careless and silly mistake, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Just as a side-comment, you should probably be using `express-handlebars` instead of `express3-handlebars`.

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: Looks like it's an old package for ExpressJS 3.X version.